# Sequelize not making migration when file does not exist in SequelizeMeta

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js, sequelize-cli

[Configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZSxWg.png)Using Sequelize in chrome I did a migrarion and realized it had errors so I undid it. Now trying to run in again it tell me there are no pending migrations. I can not do undo all migrarion as it will afect my db.

I have cheked Sequelize Meta and the file is not there.
I have changed the name to see if it would identify it. Still no luck.
I created a new migration and also no luck.

Can someone please help me.
I have pg@latest and node 16

Comment: Please show Sequelize configuration used for CLI and connection settings as well. Also pplease show the code you did to `undid` the migration.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the help. I edited the question with the details. I have done multiple migrations so i do not believe it is an issue with the configuration.

Comment: Did you check all schemas in DB weather they store SequelizeMeta or not?